# ObjectOutput writing corrupt bytes

Tags: java, file-io, ftp

So what I'm trying to accomplish is create a new file on my FTP server and then write to the file. Here is my code

```
try {

    URL  url = new URL("ftp://" + user + ":" + pass + "@127.0.0.1/myFile.txt;type=i");
    URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();

    OutputStream os = urlc.getOutputStream();
    OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
    ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);

    //I Write Here

    buffer.close();
    os.close();
    output.close();

} catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Regardless of how I write to the file

```
output.writeBytes("Hello World");
output.writeChars("Hello World");
output.writeUTF("Hello World");
output.writeObject("Hello World");
```

The output is

```
¬í
```

Also, everything is working fine but I get this in my Console

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.flush(ObjectOutputStream.java:1823)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.flush(ObjectOutputStream.java:719)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.close(ObjectOutputStream.java:740)
    at test.Upload.main(Upload.java:30)
```

Is it normal?

Line 30 is:

```
output.close();
```

Comment: show the rest of your "i write here" code, or at least how you manage the stream and conneciton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use an ObjectOutputStream unless you plan to write objects and read the stream using an ObjectInputStream. It adds a little protocol of its own to every write.

Use a DataOutputStream.

Comment: Changing the ObjectOutputStream to a DataOutputStream and then using writeBytes(""); works like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are closing your streams in the wrong order.  Always close from the "top" down (in this case the ObjectOutputStream is the "top").

When you call `buffer.close()` you close the underlying socket.  The `ObjectOutputStream.close()` method wants to write additional info before closing, but the socket is closed by the time you call `output.close()`.

Comment: Or just close the `ObjectOutputStream` and rely on it propagating.

Comment: @kdgregory - that, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think at the very least you'll need to create a File object first.

Try reading this:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/32031-ftp-in-java-using-apache-commons-net/

edit: apparently using the url connection class by itself is supposed to work. i think your issue is with your ftp server itself. the problem with your using url connection is that you won't be able to see the response the server gave you

Comment: The FTP server I'm using is on my localhost.